# MongDB Transaction Two Phase Commit

Tags: mongodb

I am bit confused about this example on two phase commit in Mongo site, What are the Transfer Information and State? Are they valid mongo keywords?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: Got it, so is there any other way to achieve transactions? especially at the application code level? I looked at the Java driver that mongo provides and Spring Data but couldnt find any support(unless I am missing something) what about support from third party like kundera? zookeeper?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not "valid mongo keywords."

"Transfer information" is just part of the example. It's used as an umbrella term for various fields on the document. The document itself is basically nothing *but* information about the transfer. "State" is a specific field on the document.